# delete partial memory of the pointer

Tags: c++, new-operator, realloc

Is there any way i can delete the partial memory of the pointer.?
for example

```
char *c = new char[1000];
sprintf(c,"this is it");
```

As it can be seen a lot of memory is getting wasted here. can I free the memory more than the required.?

Comment: Short answer: No. Why not just use `std::string`? If you really need to, you can use `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. The best you can do in C++ is to make a new copy that's the right size and delete the old one. There's no analog of C's `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your system is a RAM-restricted embedded system, why bother?  Just use ginormous buffers and include a 'dataLen' int.

Answer (score 0):

Well, allocate another memory block with the precise size required for the data, copy the data there and free the original (exceedingly large) memory block. Done.